# Redis GUI for PCF

Tags: redis, cloud-foundry

I have created an Redis instance from PCF's marketplace. I would like to know if there's any GUI tool availabe with Pivotal which i can upload in to my PCF Space and see the data in my Redis ?

Comment: what kind of graphical interface do you mean? Something like this https://prnt.sc/tajdgj ?

Comment: yes.. something like what you shared.. I will upload that in to my PCF space and connect to the redis marketplace service

Comment: please check https://redislabs.com/redisinsight/ for features and installation guide.

Answer (score 2):

[RedisInsight](https://www.redislabs.com/redisinsight) is web based Redis Client can also be easily deployed as [docker container](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/ri/installing/install-docker/).